# Determine number of runs is significant at 5% level of significance

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance, median

I have the following question to answer:

> The total thickness X of the four pads of 36 half-ring (H-R) mounts
>   for aircraft engines, taken periodically from the production line,
>   were found to be as shown below. Determine whether the total number of
>   runs above and below the median of this sequence of values of X is
>   significantly different from its expected value at the 5% level of
>   significance, under the hypothesis that X is under statistical
>   control. [image]

I believe this involves Chi Square but I honestly don't know where to begin.